# How can I solve crashes with error “passthrough is not supported, GL is disable”

Tags: crash

when I use Fortnite or any other epic game, the game crash with the error above.
Thanks for help.

I try to reinstall and update windows and drivers, but it doesn’t work. (I don’t understand what is GL, I know OpenGL, but not GL).